# sinatra, rack auth basic and lookup from file

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

using **rack::auth::basic** in a sinatra application, there is a way that i can *lookup users and password* from simple yaml file (doesn't matter if password is kept in clear)?

example yaml config/users.yml

```
---
:users:
  usersA:
    :password: passwordA
    :otherdata: xxxxx
  userB:
    :password: passwordB
```

the sinatra configure block i'm trying (with no success). how i can lookup the users from the yaml file?

```
configure do
  config = YAML::load_file(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'users.yml'))   
  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "login" do |u, p|
  [u, p] == [u, config[:users][username][:password]]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as:

```
configure do
  config = YAML::load_file(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'users.yml'))   
  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "login" do |u, p|
    p == config[:users][u][:password]
  end
end
```

You may also consider storing passwords as SHA1 and checking as:

```
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(p) == config[:users][u][:password]
```